# Exec shows invalid syntax when using with DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which named data.
Data contains 3 column names includes 'date, 'win', 'lose'.
I want to replace the nested for loop with exec to do one-liner coding.
From

```
dictNum = defaultdict(int)
for x in data.loc[:,'win']:
    for y in x:
        dictNum[y] = dictNum[y] + 1
```

To

```
dictNum = defaultdict(int)
exec('for x in data.loc[:,'win']:\n for y in x:\n   dictNum[y] = dictNum[y] + 1')
```

The error is: SyntaxError: invalid syntax at 'win'

My temporary solution is:

```
dictNum = defaultdict(int)
win = 'win'
exec('for x in data.loc[:,win]:\n for y in x:\n   dictNum[y] = dictNum[y] + 1')
```

However, I am willing to learn more methods to fix this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using `"` to surround your variable instead of `'`

Comment: There is rarely a good reason to use `exec()` and this is not one of them.

Comment: Your one line is far less readable than your nested loop. Newlines in the source code do not slow your code down.